# Does P2P Matchmaking can make an online game without any cost?

Tags: unity, c#, multiplayer

I’m planning on making an online game. I’ve used Unity (with Photon’s PUN2), but after some research, I had the idea of instead of using a server, with ccu limit and charge fees, i could make a P2P multiplayer game, so that way, the server would be one of the two players, without having any cost on me.
I don’t know If this is possible, and indeed, a good idea. I did a research on this but I couldn’t find a clear explanation or tutorial.
PS: It’s not a big game (2d game) think of it as the size of an online version of PONG, where two players fight until one wins, it could have or not a time limit.

Answer (score 1):

Many multiplayer games allow hosting a server on player machine. **That's actually a feature people like to have.**

But matchmaking requires a server on your side(or hosted by community, actually anything as long as it can be discovered easily in game).

You can avoid costs by allowing players to join only via IP, but that's going to limit your player base to those who can handle router and firewall configuration(if they even care enough).

So, you have few options here:

1. Host your own "Master" Server, that keeps track of player hosted servers.
2. Use online subsystem like Steam
3. Ignore it, and leave players to handle connectivity issuses

**What you really should do now is implement a P2P server, that's the thing you will need anyway, everything else is "just a feature".**

Comment: Could I be able to use Facebook for finding IP’s?, or is it possible to just use a random matching?

Comment: Btw, I thought of the multiplayer system something like this: One player is not the server until both connect, and when the match ends, then they disconnect. Like if it was a temporal server.

Comment: 1. Sorry, I'm not familiar with any specific system. Though i know facebook had multiplayer games connecting with it. You can read through ( developers.facebook.com/docs/games/ ) to get some info.

2. You're talking about server instance ( I guess ). A single machine can create many of these( if resources allow it ). It still requires a "master" server to group players and request one to be a host, while telling others where to connect to.

Comment: I just noticed, that you're using an external library for multiplayer (PUN2). I'd suggest creating your server locally, on your machine. If done right, it doesnt really matter where you put it later. I'm sorry I can't provide you with more technical info, I can only recommend reading through whole Photon's documentation. You're on a right track here, just dig up :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I’m not using PUN2, I have used PUN2, but it has a limit of 20 ccu, that’s why I’m looking for a better way, without ccu limit and cheaper (I’m an indie single developer)